# @mipmap/ic_launcher not being used for app icon

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm changing the app launcher icon and have modified the `res/mipmap/ic_launcher` icons using the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio). In Android Studio, I see the correct modified icon.

However, the original default icon is still being shown on the device, not the new one that I have tied to `ic_launcher`. My manifest is using pointing to the new values AFAICT.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.anytune.rxsongbrowsertrials">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
....
</manifest>
```

Why isn't the `ic_launcher` icon being used?

Comment: Try to delete all the existing icons in various folders of mipmap i.e mipmap-hdpi, xhdpi etc.

Comment: I checked both from the Android Studio view of the mipmap ic_launcher files and on the file system, and only the new icons exist. I have deleted the app from the device, and cleaned and rebuilt the project. Still getting the old icon. I have no idea where it could be coming from.

Comment: Have you changed both the normal as well as round icon?

Comment: Yes, they are both shown in my manifest above. Both pointing to the same @mipmap/ic_launcher, and I check that it is the right version for the various resolutions.

Comment: Is there a generic resolution that may be missing?

Comment: OH - the anydpi-v26 version didn't get updated, and was still pointing to the wrong drawable. I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Finally found that..lol

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. Using the [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) tool it created my new launch icon in the the ic_launcher resources for both the normal (res/mipmap/ic_launcher) and round versions (res/mipmap/ic_launcher_round) versions in the following resolutions: `dpi, dpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi`. These are all png files though, so something may still be wrong with these files, as I'm expecting them to be .xml files.

However, it did not update the `anydpi-v26` resolution. This was still referring to the original drawable with the template image. I needed to manually update the foreground tag to use my new drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your new icon with this plugin, and rename it like customIcon, set replace @mipmap/ic_launcher for @drawable/customIcon . extension isn't needed, make sure to replace it in rounded and normal

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer

Here you have a example from one working project

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_new"
    android:label="AMVT App Móvil"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_new"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

also if you need to create a simple icon you can use this tool
[Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

Comment: It isn't clear how this plugin helps. I have a `.svg` file of my app icon I want to use, and used the Android Asset Studio previously, which gave the previous problem. I don't see how to use this plugin to accept my `.svg` file. Does it even create the mipmap files, or does it just create drawables that can work and be sized correctly?

Comment: install the plugin and follow these steps
https://i.imgur.com/P3O0IvC.png
Then press + 
Select your File and the res
https://i.imgur.com/YbiNEtD.png